# Order Statistics Question

Tags: probability, sample, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

A random sample of size 10 is drawn from a Uniform distribution on [0,1].  Calculate the probability that the third order statistic is greater than 0.50.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown no attempted solution so there is no way to know
the exact approach you are intended to take for this assignment.

Many mathematical statistics books have a [general formula](https://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/the-order-statistics-and-the-uniform-distribution/#:%7E:text=The%20Order%20Statistics%20of%20the%20Uniform%20Distribution%20Suppose,probability%20density%20function%20of%20the%20order%20statistic%20is%3A) for
the density function of the $k$th order statistic of a sample
from a distribution in terms of the CDF of the population distribution.

In this case, where the population distribution is standard uniform, the
formula easily simplifies to show that order statistics of a
uniform sample have distributions in the [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) family. From there
it is trivial to find the mean of the third order statistic out of ten.

To illustrate, here is a simulation in R based on a 100,000 samples of
size $n=10.$

```
set.seed(2020)
u.3 = replicate(10^5, sort(runif(10))[3])
mean(u.3)
[1] 0.272989    # aprx mean;  exact 3/11
mean(u.3 > .5)
[1] 0.0548      # aprx prob > .5;  exact 0.0546875

hist(u.3, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dbeta(x,3,8), 0, 1, add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The mean of the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(3, 8)$ is $\mu = \frac{3}{3+8} = \frac{3}{11} =  0.2727,$ which is closely matched by the approximate value $0.2730$
from the simulation. With 100,000 iterations one can expect two or three place accuracy.

*Note:* Very roughly and intuitively, one might expect ten observations from
$\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ to be spaced on average among 11 intervening intervals (including one at each end), so that the
third order statistic would be on average $3/11$ of the way from $0$ to $1.$

Comment: thanks for your comment but it seems that the answers were pertaining to the expected value of third-order statistics. I'm a bit confused since I'm looking for the third-order stat that is greater than 0.50

Comment: Of course, the main point is to get the correct distribution. Then you can find whatever you want. // I think you're looking for the _probability_  $P(U_{3:10} >.5)$ for third order-statistic $U_{3:10} \sim\mathsf{Unif}(3,8).$ You can get that by integrating the density function or in R with `1 -pbeta(.5,3,8)`, which returns $0.0546875.$ // Also adding this step to the simulation in my answer to show an approximation.

Comment: I hope you will find this site useful. However, it is important for you to "tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. ... [J]ust posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you" doesn't work well here. .

Comment: noted with thanks